# How can I expand things from a superclass? (Java)

Tags: java, inheritance, acm-java-libraries

I want to expand the method `setValueAt(int row, int col, int value)` from the superclass `NumberBoard` in my subclass `Sudoku`.

In Sudoku the `value` is empty or 1 to 9, but in the superclass `NumberBoard` the value may be empty or `>= 0`. How can I change it in my subclass `Sudoku`?

The superclass `NumberBoard` (I can't change the superclass):

```
public class NumberBoard {

/** Value of an empty cell. */
public static final int EMPTY = -1;

/** The board's state. */
private int[][] board;

/**
 * Sets the value of the given cell.
 * 
 * @param row
 *            the cell's row, starting at 0.
 * @param col
 *            the cell's column, starting at 0.
 * @param value
 *            the cell's value. Must be {@code >= 0} or {@link #EMPTY}.
 */
public void setValueAt(int row, int col, int value) {
    if (isInRange(row, col) && (value == EMPTY || value >= 0)) {
        board[row][col] = value;
    }
}


/**
 * Checks if the given coordinates identify a valid cell on the board.
 * 
 * @param row
 *            the cell's row, starting at 0.
 * @param col
 *            the cell's column, starting at 0.
 * @return {@code true} if the coordinate is in range, {@code false}
 *         Â otherwise.
 */
protected final boolean isInRange(int row, int col) {
    return 0 <= row
            && row < board.length
            && 0 <= col
            && col < board[row].length;
  }
}
```

And my Code for my subclass `Sudoku` (Unfortunately without a point) :

```
public class Sudoku extends NumberBoard {


public void setValueAt(int row, int col, int value) {
    super.setValueAt(row, col, value);      
    }
  }
```

Comment: What does it mean to "expand a method"?

Comment: You don't need to redefine `setValueAt`. But you probably want to override `isInRange()`.

Comment: You shouldn't use inheritance. Since a Sudoku can't do all that a NumberBoard is supposed to do, it doesn't satify the Liskov principle, and should thus not inherit from NumberBoard. Use delegation instead. *Use* a NumberBoard inside Sudoku.

Comment: I want to change things in it. For example the value for my Sudoku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Sudoku the value is empty or 1 to 9, but in the superclass
>   NumberBoard the value may be empty or >= 0. How can I change it in my
>   subclass Sudoku?

You could create your own exception to handle the error case :

```
public class IncorectValueException extends Exception{
  public IncorectValueException(){
    super();
  }
}
```

Besides, in `NumberBoard` class, in `setValueAt()` method you perform too many unitary processings which should be grouped in a specific method if you want to redefine the behavior of checking valid data according to the class :

```
`isInRange(row, col) && (value == EMPTY || value >= 0)`
```

could be a new method : `isAcceptableValue(int row, int col, int value)`

Change it :

```
public void setValueAt(int row, int col, int value) throws IncorectValueException{
    if (isInRange(row, col) && (value == EMPTY || value >= 0)) {
        board[row][col] = value;
    }
}
```

to :

```
public void setValueAt(int row, int col, int value) throws IncorectValueException{
    if (!isAcceptableValue(row, col)) {
       throw new IncorectValueException();             
    }
      board[row][col] = value;
}

public boolean isAcceptableValue(int row, int col, int value){
   if(isInRange(row, col) && (value == EMPTY || value >= 0)){
     return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Now, the  `Sudoku` class could be like that :

```
public class Sudoku extends NumberBoard {
     ...
public boolean isAcceptableValue(int row, int col, int value){ 
   if(isInRange(row, col) && (value==EMPTY || (value >= 1 && value <= 9))) {
      return true;             
    }       
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check for value in subclass like

```
public class Sudoku extends NumberBoard {

    public void setValueAt(int row, int col, int value) {
        if(value <= 9 && value >= 1 ) {
            super.setValueAt(row, col, value);      
        } else {
           throw IllegalArgumentException ("value can be empty or between 1 & 9 (inclusive)")
        }

    }
}
```

Here you can accept null as int wont allow null values.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question a few times, I finally understood what you want. If do not want to run the implementation inherited from the superclass, you can `override` the method:

```
public class Sudoku extends NumberBoard {

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(int row, int col, int value) {
        //do not invoke super.setValueAt() here
        //Write your new implementation here
    }
}
```

Your override `setValueAt()` by writing a new set of implementation in it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for an Override here, to redefine the range of values that 'value' can take.

You could go for an Override as shown below,

```
public class Sudoku extends NumberBoard {

  @Override
  public void setValueAt(int row, int col, int value) {
    if (value > 0 && value <= 9) { // Considering EMPTY just means 0 as int is primitive
      super.setValueAt(row, col, value);
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value cannot be negative or greater than 9");
    }
  }
}
```

However, a better design would be to have, may be a separate EnhancedNumberBoard class (local inner class, if required) override the method and use it as a member variable by object composition.